# Passing argument to function (ajax, javascript, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass the `x` argument to the function `startTable`?
I want to filter results by author, and have been stuck on this for a few days...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result;
    alert('ajax works');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml.php",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            function startTable(x) {
                $(xml).find("item").each(function (index) {
                    var author = $(this).find('author').text();
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    var rating = $(this).find('rating').text();
                    var review = $(this).find('review').text();
                    // Checks the condition
                    if (author == x) {
                        $('#input1').append('<tr><td>Title: <b>' + title + '</b></td><td>Rating: <b>' + rating + '</b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">' + review + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                });
            };

        }
    });
});

function startFilter() {
    var x = document.getElementById('inputFilter').value;
    // Passing parameter
    startTable(x);
};
```

Any Ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `startTable`'s scope is the succes function, yet you are calling it from outside of that scope. it doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your code to call the ajax, then used it - all started by execution.  This is a bit clunky but that you can work on.

```
function startTable(x, xml) {
    $(xml).find("item").each(function (index) {
        var xmlItem = $(this);
        if (xmlItem.find('author').text() == x) {
            var thisItem = {
                title: xmlItem.find('title').text(),
                rating: xmlItem.find('rating').text(),
                review: xmlItem.find('review').text()
            };
            $('#input1').append('<tr><td>Title: <b>' + thisItem.title + '</b></td><td>Rating: <b>' + thisItem.rating + '</b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">' + thisItem.review + '</td></tr>');
        }
    });
}

function getData(x) {
    var result;
    alert('ajax works');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml.php",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            startTable(x, xml);
        }
    });
}

function startFilter() {
    var x = document.getElementById('inputFilter').value;
    // Passing parameter
    getData(x);
}

//get started
startFilter();
```

Now it might just be me, but you might filter your results on the server (passing the "x" value and only send back what you need, but that is up to you.

Comment: one more question... function .append adds stuff to the div, what function rewrites div?

Comment: `.html(newcontent)` - but that is NOT for the input tag, only for a div, span etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call a local function from outside. What you should do is filtering the response data inside the success callback function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml.php",
    success: function (response) {
      render_and_filter(response);
    }
});

function render_and_filter(data){
 // ... append or update your data to document here ...
}
```